# Sending message to a Client with JButton in java

Tags: java, swing, client, server

I have a Java program where run-time JButtons are generated whenever a new client connects to my server program. I need to send a message to a particular client only when a JButton is clicked which is assigned for that particular Client.

```
void connect_clients()
    {
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
            jButton2.setText("Server Running!");
            jButton2.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                while (true) {

                    socket = listener.accept();
                    try {

                           //  System.out.println("Client connected from " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
                            clientIP= socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName();
                            buttons.add(new JButton(clientIP));
                           displayButton(buttons.get(clientNumber),clientNumber);
                            clientNumber++;

                 } 
                    finally {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally {
                listener.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test_Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I tried something like this.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) throws IOException{
    if ( e.getSource() == buttons.get(1) )
    {
        String thisIP = buttons.get(1).getText();
        PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                         out.println("hey");
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"gfb");
    }
  }
```

These are declared gobally:

```
String clientIP = "";
    int clientNumber = 0;
    ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    Socket socket;
```

Comment: If you close the client's socket as soon as you create the button, you won't be able to send anything to her later...

Comment: So what is the solution for this? Should I remove the socket.close() and listener.close()? And one more thing why is my actionperformed method is not working when I click on my UI?

Comment: Three things; 1- You close the client Socket when it's connected; 2- You seem to updating the UI from outside the context of the EDT and also blocking the EDT; 3- You don't have a Socket connection to each individual client, since you have only have one reference to Socket, but you close it anyway

Comment: How can I have connection to each and individuals client? This is one thing I have been trying to get but I don't have any idea.

Comment: can u guide me @MadProgrammer

Comment: first, remove socket.close();  you can not close a socket if you are planning to use it later, then if you know how to use HashMaps, then you can map each button to the socket so that it can be retrieved from the HashMap using the button object in the actionPerformed method.  I can provide an example if needed.

Comment: You should keep an open Socket connection to each client if you want to be able to send them anything. For example, you could store them in a Map<JButton, Socket>, to be able to retrieve which Socket belongs to which JButton.

Comment: Yes i need a example @faljbour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code modified to use TreeMap (sorted HashMap) instead of ArrayList where each button is mapped to a socket object, notice that the socket is no longer global.  Let me know if something is not clear.

```
  int clientNumber = 0;
  TreeMap buttonsMap = new TreeMap();
  buttonListener blistener = new buttonListener();
  void connect_clients()
    {
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
            jButton2.setText("Server Running!");
            jButton2.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                while (true) {

                    Socket socket = listener.accept();
                    try {

                         //  System.out.println("Client connected from " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
                         String clientIP= socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName();
                         JButton button = new JButton(clientIP);
                        button.addActionListener(blistner);
                         buttonsMap.put(button, socket);
                         displayButton(button,clientNumber);
                         clientNumber++;

                 } 
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                 }
               }
            }
            finally {
                listener.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test_Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }



private class buttonListener implements ActionListener
  {  
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) throws IOException{
        if ( JButton button= e.getSource())
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)buttonsMap.get(button);
            PrintWriter out =
                            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                             out.println("hey");
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"gfb");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have just modified the code to make sure that you use the same actionListener for each button

Comment: My server program generates runtime buttons when a clients connects to it. Will it be able to work with your example code?

Comment: This is the same code you provided using a hashmap, yes a button is created once a client connect

Comment: `buttonListener blistener = new buttonListener();` what do u refer to buttonListener here? I dont get it. @faljbour

Comment: I am not sure how you assigned an action listener to the JButtons in your original code, you do not show it in your original code, but it is used to assign the same action listener to each button in this line of code, "button.addActionListener(blistner);"  it could be redundant, examine your code in the displayButton to see if it is needed, or show the code for this method in your question.